# Integral of kernel in RKHS with respect to probability measure

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm trying to understand how to work with the expression $$ \int u (d\mu-d\pi)$$ where $u\in \mathcal{H}$, an RKHS. $\mu$ and $\pi$ here are two different probability measures. Since $\mathcal{H}$ is an RKHS, it has a corresponding kernel $k$, but I wonder how to express this above integral in terms of the kernel function.

Something tells me I should be able to rewrite this in terms of $\int k(x,y)\,d\mu(x)\,d\mu(y)$, $\int k(x,y)\,d\mu(x)\,d\pi(y)$, and $\int k(x,y)\,d\pi(x)\,d\pi(y)$, but I don't see how. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question a bit?

Comment: I would like to minimize $\int u (d\mu-d\pi) + \left\|u\right\|^2_{\mathcal{H}}$ where $\mathcal{H}$ is an RKHS. My advisor has a hunch it can be written in terms of the above three integrals but I don't see how.